# .env keyError in django project

Tags: django, environment-variables

I'm having a hard time because my django project.
Who can help?
I'd like to thank you for your help.

set `.env` in proeject Root path

```
SECRET_KEY=exampleKey
DEBUG=False


DB_ENGINE=django.db.backends.mysql
DB_NAME=example
DB_USER=admin

...Blah Blah
```

project `settings.py`

```
import os
import environ

env = environ.Env(DEBUG=(bool, False), )
environ.Env.read_env()

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY')

DEBUG = env('DEBUG')

...Blah Blah
```

And when run the project
I get an this error message.

```
Django_workspace/asone/asone/.env doesn't exist - if you're not configuring your environment separately, create one.
  "environment separately, create one." % env_file)

    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'SECRET_KEY'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

/Django_workspace/asone/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/environ/environ.py", line 277, in get_value
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the SECRET_KEY environment variable
```

I have a hard time because I'm a django beginner.
Who can help? I'd like to thank you for your help.

---

.P.S

Thank you so much for your answer.
I'm sorry. I'm telling you, there's something I missed out on.

I set up a `django-environ` package to use the `.env` in the project.

```
pip install django-environ
```

Is there something I'm missing?
What more information will be needed to solve this problem?

---

.P.S

set up python-dotenv package

```sh
pip install python-dotenv.
```

Change settings.py

```py
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

...

SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')
DEBUG=os.getenv('DEBUG')

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        # 'ENGINE': env('DB_ENGINE'),
        # 'NAME': env('DB_NAME'),
        # 'USER': env('DB_USER'),
        # 'PASSWORD': env('DB_PASSWORD'),
        # 'HOST': env('DB_HOST'),
        # 'PORT': env('DB_PORT'),
        'ENGINE': os.getenv('DB_ENGINE'), 
        'NAME': os.getenv('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': os.getenv('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': os.getenv('DB_HOST'),
        'PORT': os.getenv('DB_PORT'),
    }
}
...
```

and then I met this error message.

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/logging/config.py", line 562, in configure
    handler = self.configure_handler(handlers[name])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/logging/config.py", line 735, in configure_handler
    result = factory(**kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/logging/handlers.py", line 148, in __init__
    BaseRotatingHandler.__init__(self, filename, mode, encoding, delay)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/logging/handlers.py", line 55, in __init__
    logging.FileHandler.__init__(self, filename, mode, encoding, delay)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1087, in __init__
    StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1116, in _open
    return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/haemil/Desktop/Back-end workspace/Django_workspace/asone/logs/logfile'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/haemil/Desktop/Back-end workspace/Django_workspace/asone/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/haemil/Desktop/Back-end workspace/Django_workspace/asone/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Users/haemil/Desktop/Back-end workspace/Django_workspace/asone/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/Users/haemil/Desktop/Back-end workspace/Django_workspace/asone/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/Users/haemil/Desktop/Back-end workspace/Django_workspace/asone/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/haemil/Desktop/Back-end workspace/Django_workspace/asone/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/Users/haemil/Desktop/Back-end workspace/Django_workspace/asone/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 75, in configure_logging
    logging_config_func(logging_settings)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/logging/config.py", line 799, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/logging/config.py", line 570, in configure
    '%r' % name) from e
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'file'
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: why do you need to set .env path?

Comment: I put it in root rather than in setting it up. `project/.env`  
Is there anything else I need to answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `environ` module in `stdlib`(standard library of python). So I checked if there is third party module called 'environ' by running `pip install environ`, which installed it, but when I checked at [pypi website](https://pypi.org/project/environ/), I can't see any valid explanation. I think it's not maintained well.

So I concluded that your environ configuration went a bit odd.

Here's my suggestion

1. Install [python-dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) module by running `pip install python-dotenv`. There are many `.env` module, but this is one of the most popular, well maintained one in my opinion.
2. Ensure your `.env` file is in the directory where `settings.py` is. `setting.py` will load `.env` file in the same directory unless specified otherwise
3. Change your code from this

```
import os
import environ

env = environ.Env(DEBUG=(bool, False), )
environ.Env.read_env()

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY')

DEBUG = env('DEBUG')
```

to this

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

...

SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')
DEBUG=os.getenv('DEBUG')

...
```

Change your db setting similar way

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': os.getenv('DB_ENGINE'), 
        'NAME': os.getenv('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': os.getenv('DB_USER'),
        # and so on ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I'll apply your answer to the project

Comment: First of all,  I’m really grateful for your help. I followed your solution. and then I met this error message. `ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'file'` Is there something I'm missing? What more information will be needed to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you install python-dotenv by running `pip install python-dotenv` in your virtual environment? Or did you run `pip install python-dotenv.`?

Comment: I owe you one. Thanks for explaining this to me.

Comment: I think I installed it in a virtual environment. Can you continue this problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63516502/django-valueerror-unable-to-configure-handler-file

Comment: `python3 -m venv venv` and then `$ source venv/bin/activate` and then `install pip install python-dotenv`

Answer (score 0):

You are running into a KeyError because either:

1. You aren't putting a SECRET_KEY variable in your `.env` file.
2. It can't find your `.env` file.

From what I can see from your answer, try moving your `.env` file from your root directory to where it will sit alongside `settings.py`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.
I'll apply your answer to the project.

Comment: put them side by side, and there was an new error. error message is `ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'file'` thanks for your answer..! I really want to thank you for your help.